# How can populate table for status with php mysql query with 1 or 0?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show a status of active and inactive with php, and the value for active is 1 and for inactive is 0; How can i pu `$status = ($row['is_active'])?'<span>Active</span>':'<span>Deactivited</span>';` variable in `<td><?php echo $row->role; ?> <?php echo $status; ?></td>`
here is my code

```
<?php
    $status = ($row['is_active'])?'<span class="label label-success pull-right">Active</span>':'<span class="label label-danger pull-right">Deactivited</span>';
    $no = 1;
    $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
    $select->execute();
    while($row=$select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->username; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->fullname; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->role; ?> <?php echo $status; ?></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#"
            onclick="return confirm('Delete User?')"
            class="btn"</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: @jeff Answer in the answer section not the comments section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the check for the `$row['is_active']` into the for loop.

Here's an implementation.

```
<?php
    $no = 1;
    $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
    $select->execute();
    while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $status = ($row->is_active) ? '<span class="label label-success pull-right">Active</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger pull-right">Deactivited</span>';
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->username; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->fullname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->role; ?><?php echo $status; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#"
                   onclick="return confirm('Delete User?')"
                   class="btn"</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked just corrected the error `$status = ($row->is_active)`